# Извлечь текст по атрибуту xml

Tags: c#, xml

Сап
Мне нужно извлечь значение из xml файла по атрибуту
Строчка xml выглядит так

```
<item name='FromSK'><text/>1</item>
```

Но сложность не в этом
XML состоит из двух больших тега  с атрибутами input и instruction
Строка `<item name='FromSK'><text/>1</item>` может повторяться и там и там
Мне же нужно извлечь только из `<document form='Input'>`
Пытался сделать так, почти получилось, он кидает файлы, даже если во втором `<document>` существует attr с именем FromSK
Понимаю, что нужно искать во вложенном тексте (innerXml/innerText), но до конца не въезжаю

Код: https://ghostbin.co/paste/dth2e

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string sourceFileName;
            string destFileName;

            int docsCount = 0;

            Console.Write("Путь у докам: ");
            sourceFileName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Путь к папке экспорта: ");
            destFileName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFileName, "*.xml");

            for (int file = 0; file < files.Length; file++) {
                try {
                    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                    XmlDoc.Load(files[file]);
                    foreach (XmlNode docNode in XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("document").Item(0)) {
                        foreach (XmlNode itemNode in XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < itemNode.Attributes.Count; i++) {
                                if (itemNode.Attributes.Item(i).Value == "FromSK" && itemNode.InnerText == "1") {
                                    //string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourceFileName, files[file]);
                                    //File.Move(sourceFile, destFileName + files[file].Substring(files[file].LastIndexOf('\\')));
                                    //docsCount++;
                                    //Console.WriteLine($"Файл {files[file]} перемещен");
                                    //break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Перемещено файлов: " + docsCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<database xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.0'>
    <document form='Input'>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='FromSK'>1<text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/>sometext</item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/>sometext</item>
    </item></document>
    
    <document form='Instruction'>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='FromSK'>1<text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text>sometext</text></item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/>sometext</item>
    <item name='sometext'><text/>sometext</item>
    </item></document>
 </database>
```

Comment: Я думаю, вам поможет десереализация. Покажите полный пример XML файла, можете выкинуть из него лишние ноды, лишь бы была понятна ключевая иерархия, внутри которой лежит нужный вам тег.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/iFYQE
тут xml файл

Comment: Вставьте текст из файла прямо в вопрос.

Comment: То есть вам надо единичку `1` извлечь?

Comment: Да, мне нужно извлечь единицу, но с тега <document form='input'>
Потому что во втором теге может и не быть значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала попробую показать код, максимально приближенный к вашему.

В первом цикле проходим по элементам "document". В условии `if` находим тот, у которого атрибут равен "Input".

В другом цикле проходим по дочерним узлам. Опять же, находим нужный "item" с атрибутом равным "FromSK". Этот цикл `for` с `if` можно заменить на `GetNamedItem`, как сделано для "document" - это сократит код.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");

foreach (XmlNode document in xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("document"))
{
    if (document.Attributes.GetNamedItem("form").Value == "Input")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode itemNode in document.ChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemNode.Attributes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (itemNode.Attributes[i].Value == "FromSK")
                {
                    Console.Write(itemNode.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Такой код выглядит ужасно и громоздко, поэтому давайте используем другой способ, с применением XPath.
При этом обязательно нужно учитывать пространства имён. В вашем xml оно есть: `xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl'`.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");

var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.lotus.com/dxl");

string xpath = "//ns:document[@form='Input']/ns:item[@name='FromSK']";

var itemNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, manager);
string text = itemNode.InnerText;
```

Такой код намного лаконичней.

---

Ещё лучше использовать LINQ to XML. Этот способ является рекомендуемым в современной разработке.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.lotus.com/dxl";

string text = xml
    .Elements(ns + "document")
    .First(elem => elem.Attribute("form").Value == "Input")
    .Elements(ns + "item")
    .First(item => item.Attribute("name").Value == "FromSK")
    .Value;
```

Здесь тоже нужно учитывать пространства имён.

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли